# Android app crashes on Android studio when 'ok' button is pressed without selecting any radio button

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am working on an android project using java. I have a dialog window which consists of multiple buttons.When I press ok button without selecting any of the radio buttons my app crashes. I am displaying the user selected radio button to the user. I used default radio button to prevent it from crashing but still emulator exits on it's own. I am using setMultiChoiceItems. I

```
public AlertDialog.Builder setMultiChoiceItems (CharSequence[] items, 
                boolean[] checkedItems, 
                DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener)
```

Comment: Whenever there is a crash there is a stacktrace . Check logs and add the stacktrace with question

Comment: I see no button. Nor code that would cause an exception.